# I want to calculate the integral of following function;

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I WANT TO calculate the integral of following function:

$$\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } (x,y)\in I \text{ and } y > x, \\
0 & \text{if } (x,y)\in I \text{ and } y\le x
\end{cases}$$

By using Darboux sum convergence Criterion.

$I=[0,1]\times [0,1]$

Comment: What is "$I$"? Also, what have you tried so far on this problem?

Comment: *wanna*? Is it so much more work to write proper written English?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think the meaning is still clear. I think that as long as it's legible, it's fine.

Comment: Ok I gss y cn tk tht pstion.

Comment: Okay I editted. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Now if it were written like that I believe it would be cause for concern.

Comment: $I=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ @ZevChonoles sorry I forgot.

Comment: But I dont understand what you disturb? @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez because of american english or informal.. Etc? But this word is not rude in spite of informal. By the way I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @Bstr what is your domain of integration?

Comment: Pretty sure he is integrating over $I$.

Comment: That's so you ask $I$? $I=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ please show me the solution. Thank you:) @Kaster

Comment: Keep it down y'all, we're gonna have to migrate to [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) at this rate.

Comment: I know English. I dont need the site @AlexanderGruber

Comment: I know, @Bstr. That was directed at those nitpicking your grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to make a sequence of partitions so that the rectangles covering $\{(x, y): x = y\}$ become smaller and smaller. The other rectangles don't matter since the function is constant there.

Let the partition $P_n$ be a $n \times n$ grid of squares with side length $\frac{1}{n}$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, let $N$ be an integer greater than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Consider the partition $P_N$. Then there will be $N$ squares covering $\{(x, y): x = y\}$. So we have,

$$
U(f, P_N) - L(f, P_N) = N\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2 (1 - 0) = \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon
$$

so $f$ is integrable. Now the lower and the upper sums are:

$$
L(f, P_N) = \frac{N(N - 1)}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2N} < \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
U(f, P_N) = \frac{N(N + 1)}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2N} > \frac{1}{2}
$$
since there are $\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}$ many squares where the infimum of the function is $1$; everywhere else is $0$. Similarly, there are $\frac{N(N + 1)}{2}$ many squares where supremum of the function is $1$. So for all $N$, $L(f, P_N) < \frac{1}{2} < U(f, P_N)$. Since the above showed that these upper and lower sums can be made arbitrarily close to each other, the integral must be
$$
\int_I f = \frac{1}{2}
$$